# Understanding memory leaks in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory-leaks, android-view

I found the article ["Avoiding memory leaks"](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), where it is said that the following code:

```
private static Drawable sBackground;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");

  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);

  setContentView(label);
}
```

is not a good idea, since:

> When the screen orientation changes the system will, by default,
>   destroy the current activity and create a new one while preserving its
>   state. In doing so, Android will reload the application's UI from the
>   resources.

So the above code:

> ...leaks the first activity created upon the first screen orientation change. When a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is
>   set as a callback on the drawable. In the code snippet above, this
>   means the drawable has a reference to the TextView which itself has a
>   reference to the activity (the Context) which in turns has references
>   to pretty much anything (depending on your code.)

But, when screen orientation changes, the method [setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.3_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) is called, which in turn calls:

```
background.setCallback(this);
```

The method `Drawable.setCallback()` is definied in the following way:

```
public final void setCallback(Callback cb) {
    mCallback = new WeakReference<Callback>(cb);
}
```

So, now background should release the old reference to the previous TextView, and a new reference to the new TextView should be created.

So, it seems like changing screen orientation leaks a reference only until the activity is newly created.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: In addition to the correct answer, seeing a static in an Activity should make you instinctively fell unwell (see `code smells`) and passing `this`, or `Context` or anything else which references an `Activity` to an object you cannot directly control the lifetime of, and **guarantee** that it is, at most, as long as the `Activity`, should make you vomit on the spot.

Comment: Romain Guy explains the scenarios for the memory leak in the comments on the original [blog post](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are absolutely right. However, there is one subtle point: the article is from *2009*. Back then, the implementation of `setCallback` was [different](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java/?v=diff&id2=2.3.7_r1#325):

**Android <= 2.3.7:**

```
public final void setCallback(Callback cb) {
    mCallback = cb;
}
```

**Android >= 4.0.1:**

```
public final void setCallback(Callback cb) {
    mCallback = new WeakReference<Callback>(cb);
}
```

<sub>Grepcode shows no source code of intermediate versions, this is the only diff I could quickly find.</sub>

---

So, again, you're absolutely right in this specific case (if you're targeting >14 that is). However, it is still very important to really think about what is actually happening when you keep a static reference to such items (like you did). There are numerous cases where you certainly could be leaking the `Context`.

Comment: exactly what I was checking