# on android memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In this offical blog site, I read below example of memory leak.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

```
private static Drawable sBackground;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);
  TextView label = new TextView(this);
  label.setText("Leaks are bad");
  if (sBackground == null) {
    sBackground = getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap);
  }
  label.setBackgroundDrawable(sBackground);
  setContentView(label);
}
```

To quote the original post "This code is very fast and also very wrong; it leaks the first activity created upon the first screen orientation change. When a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the drawable. In the code snippet above, this means the drawable has a reference to the TextView which itself has a reference to the activity (the Context) which in turns has references to pretty much anything (depending on your code.)"

I do not understand this part. When the activity is recreated, the onCreate() method will be executed, the static Drawable object sBackground will be attached to the new TextView in the second activity. Meaning that the object sBackground will reference to the new textview instead of the old textview in the first activity, leaving the first activity un-referenced.

Can anybody tell me where is wrong in my reasoning? Thanks in advance~~

Oops, it seems this thread is a duplicate, someone asked exactly the same thing here
[Understanding memory leaks in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244593/understanding-memory-leaks-in-android-application?rq=1)
Sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: getDrawable(R.drawable.large_bitmap) keep the reference

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know after checking the source of View class, when a Drawable is attached to a view, the view is set as a callback on the drawable. Beside, the view also keep a reference to this Drawable. Please see this link http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#16292. 
And because static variable has long lifetime, then every time you recreate activity & set a Drawable to its view, the activity and its Context also keep a reference to the static Drawable. Then take memories as long as variable does.